# Resize image and store in Storage folder

Tags: php, laravel

Why does not this work?

I want to change the size and save it in the storage folder.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('image') ?? null;
    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $name = time();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $name . '.' . $extension;
        $imageResize = Image::make($file)->resize(600, 300)->save('images/blogs/'.$fileName);
        $image = $file->storeAs('',$imageResize, 'public');
    }
    Blog::query()->create([
        'image' => $image,
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('admin.blogs.index');
}
```

I see this error

[image: error]

Images must be saved in this way

[image: save like this]

Comment: The error is informing you the process doesn't have the required write permission on the folder you're trying to save the image to.

Comment: @Peppermintology - What's the solution?

Comment: Fix your permissions. Start here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel

Comment: @waterloomatt   I did not understand at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this and if you want add time to the name of your image simply add it to the input image name.
About permission if you are an a production server please set storage directory permission to the 755 but if you are on a local windows machine check if your storage directory has not read-only attribute.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    $image = $request->file('image') ?? null;
    if ($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $input['imagename'] = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

        $destinationPath = public_path('storage/images/blogs/resized');
        $img = Image::make($image->path());
        $img->resize(600, 300, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']);

        $destinationPath = public_path('storage/images/blogs/fullSize');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $input['imagename']);
        
    }
    Blog::query()->create([
        'image' => $image,
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('admin.blogs.index')->withSuccess('Image successfully uploaded!');
}
```

Comment: I see this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5mUu.png . And I want to upload in the storage folder

Comment: you should create "storage" inside of your public directory and these subdirectories "images", "blogs", "fullSize" and "resized".

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. Can you update your post?

Comment: You have public folder, right? Open it and create new folder storage. Open storage and create new folder with name images. Open images and create new folder blogs. Open blogs and create new folders resized and fullSize. In the sample code fullSize goes with  capital S. fullSize.